# How do i upgrade osCommerce v2.2 to v2.3.1?

Tags: upgrade, oscommerce

How do i upgrade osCommerce **v2.2** to **v2.3.1**? Is there a upgrade script available for that?
Do I have to upgrade it to v2.3.0 before upgrading to v2.3.1?

Answer (score 1):

Download and unzip the latest version of osCommerce v2.3.1.  Inside the folder you will find an upgrade_guide.pdf - open it. On the very first page, it tells you how to go about upgrading.

On page 2 you'll see a reddish shaded box and it says the following:

> This upgrade guide only provides the minimum required changes in the form of security updates and bug fixes. These changes will not upgrade your store to a complete v2.3 version. Please continue to use v2.2 add-ons and do not install v2.3 optimized add-ons as the may not function with your installation. If you wish to upgrade to a full v2.3 version, perform only (SQL) Database Changes and use the database with a new v2.3 installation.

Comment: But [how do I make those Database Changes to use it with a new v2.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803262/how-do-i-upgrade-oscommerce-database-from-v2-2-to-v2-3-1)

Comment: In the same PDF that I refer to, it gives a list of the changes that are made to the database.  You need to open phpMyAdmin and copy and paste those change into the SQL tab and run those queries, alternatively, copy and paste those database changes into a text file, save it as whatever and import that text file by clicking on the Import tab and importing the text file.