# How do i upgrade osCommerce Database from v2.2 to v2.3

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

Inside the Oscommerce folder there is an upgrade_guide called upgrade-230.pdf.

there it sais

> If you wish to upgrade to a full v2.3 version, perform only (SQL) Database Changes and use the database with a new v2.3 installation.

But how do I make those **Database Changes** to use it with a new v2.3?

I think I have to manually compare database schemas and modify the old site's backup .sql file (adding/changing fields, adding tables, etc., to match the schema and fixing the corresponding INSERT statements to match). Then you can simply replace the new installation's database with the restored old one.

In the file there are only [some SQL-commands](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7330422) to create the action recorder:

```
CREATE TABLE action_recorder ( ...
```

What else do I have to change in the old database backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The databases are pretty much the same, only some small differences that you can correct with these statements, I collected the needed changes here:

> https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7330900

Or you could try the **Community Add-On** [SQL upgrades from 2.2MS to 2.3.3](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/8731).

Depending on your old version you may or may not need all of it.  Also, be sure to make a backup of your database before running any of this

Comment: I am trying to upgrade from version 2.2 to 2.3.4.1. Could you please guide me how do I do it? I've tried looking in oscommerce forums but didn't work.

Comment: What do you need to know? Did you try my links?

Comment: Yes I tried the community addon. Ran the sql queries but many of them showed an error. I am trying to upgrade from 2.2-MS2 to 2.3.4.1.

Eearlier I tried, 1. Moving a copy of all the files and db to a new server and then unzipping the new oscommerce version which would replace all the old files and then added the db name, username and pass in the include files. But it also resulted in an error. I've seen so many online forums to no avail. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What are the errors, you see? Can you post it on pastebin? Did you compare the databases? ( I don't run oscommerce any more, so I cannot try it out here)