# Categories are not displayed in Oscommerce 2.3

Tags: oscommerce

I updated my OsCommerce shop to 2.3.3.4:

- I replaced all files with the new default files from the package.
- I Updated the old database with the script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806818/1069083
- Compared an sql-dump of the old database with the dump of an empty new database, It looked all OK.

Now the new version works with all products in it, but although I activated the "Categories" box in the admin interface it is not shown on the left.

Did I forget a Detail?

Comment: A comment I was trying to add to your now deleted question: @rubo77, there may not be one [a site to ask for shop software recommendations]; Stack Exchange doesn't intend to offer a Q&A site for everything. There's a number of topic sites, and each one has its own rules. Stack Overflow has had problems with library recommendations in the past, since it is a perfect vector for spammers to ask and answer their own questions. Such queries tend to date quickly as well. If you wish, you could enter the PHP chatroom, and ask in there.

Comment: This question, unfortunately, is also likely to be closed - please do read the Help section, to save you more closures. Questions wishing to achieve some programming outcome should generally be accompanied by the code you currently have, or at least a description of what you have presently tried.

Comment: I added details about what I have tried, I hope this question is now clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why:

there are two different `configure.php` files, one is in

```
catalog/includes/configure.php
```

and one is in

```
catalog/admin/includes/configure.php
```

I didn't set the database to the new database in the admin config file, so all changes in admin didn't affect the real shop